# Getting a SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Tags: javascript, sql, sequelize.js

```
var records = "";
for(var i = 0; i < activity.length; i++) {
sequelize.query("SELECT * from users WHERE city = '"+city+"'" AND categories LIKE CONCAT('%', activity[i], '%')"", { type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT})
    .then(function(logs){ 
        records += logs;
        matchCount += logs.length;

    }); 
}

console.log("--------------------------Priniting matched users-----------------------");
console.log(records);

//INSERT DATA TO SQL

sequelize.query("INSERT INTO users(name, lastname, email, phone, city, categories, createdAt, updatedAt) VALUES ('"+req.body.first_name+"', '"+req.body.last_name+"', '"+req.body.email+"',  '"+req.body.tel+"', '"+req.body.city+"', , '"+JSON.stringify(activity)+"', 'test', 'test')");
```

Comment: Take a closer look at the `sequelize.query` call in the loop. Do the syntax highlighting looks okay to you? A good editor with syntax highlighting would have helped you. Especially if the editor also had any kind of checking for errors itself.

Comment: Typo: `'"+city+"'"`

Comment: I bet it gives a line number, champ

Answer (score 1):

You have to pay more attention to the string quotes, you screwed up between the closing simple quote of `city` and the `AND categories` part.

It should look like this:

```
sequelize.query("SELECT * from users WHERE city = '"+city+"' AND categories LIKE CONCAT('%', activity[i], '%')", { type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT})
```

Also, be careful when concatenating variables into a SQL string query, if you don't sanitize them you could be victim of a [SQL injection attack](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection)

Answer (score 0):

The error was in the select statement having wierd quotes.

```
var records = "";
for (var i = 0; i < activity.length; i++) {
    sequelize.query("SELECT * from users WHERE city = '" + city + "'AND categories LIKE CONCAT('%', activity[i], '%')", {
            type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT
        }).then(
        function(logs) {
            records += logs;
            matchCount += logs.length;
        });
}

console.log("--------------------------Priniting matched users-----------------------");
console.log(records);

//INSERT DATA TO SQL

sequelize.query("INSERT INTO users(name, lastname, email, phone, city, categories, createdAt, updatedAt) VALUES ('" + req.body.first_name + "', '" + req.body.last_name + "', '" + req.body.email + "', '" + req.body.tel + "', '" + req.body.city + "', , '" + JSON.stringify(activity) + "', 'test', 'test')");
```